# Crash in autoreleasePool drain

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have a rare **(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)** crash in [pool drain]. As I understand its caused by over-release of some object owned by the autorelease pool.

I tried using NSZombieEnabled = YES, and using Instruments with zombie tracer. The bug is not reproducible with these. There is no over-release message logged in the console and zombie tracer do not show any zombie alerts. But the crash is reproducible very frequently when I take off these flags. Anybody seen similar behaviour?

Is there any other way to debug this easily? I am using Xcode 5.0.1 in OS 10.8.5. I am pasting the crashed thread trace below:

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release

> 0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff8b3040a3 objc_msgSend +35
>
> 1   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff855d086f CFRelease + 591
>
> 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff856028a9
>   -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 249
>
> 3   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff8b30665a (anonymous
>   namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 502
>
> 4   com.apple.ist.istcore             0x000000010fb91d82
>   -[SomeFileOperation main] + 117
>
> 5   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff81f2070b
>   **NSThread__main** + 1318
>
> 6   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff86389899 _pthread_body +
>   138
>
> 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8638972a _pthread_start +
>   137
>
> 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8638dfc9 thread_start +
>   13

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put some code?

Comment: I can't put the exact code .. sorry about that. I have SomeFileOperation class (a subclass of NSOperation). I have overridden the -main method and I do stuff there related to downloading file. I have the @autoreleasepool around the code in -main method.

Comment: I am looking for ways of debugging this easily since zombie tracers are not helping here .. I see no over-release logs with NSZombieEnabled, but it crashes when this flag is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

`[__NSDictionaryM dealloc]`

A dictionary is being deallocated.

`CFRelease`

When a dictionary is being deallocated, every key and value gets a `release` message.

However, one of the objects inside the dictionary has already been deallocated, that means that sending another `release` message makes an illegal access.

Check the keys/values in your dictionary, you are overreleasing one of them. I recommend you to also perform a full project clean and then a deep analysis (see `Project` menu). In most cases, that will help you to find the bug.

You can also add a symbolic breakpoint to `NSDictionary dealloc`, wait for it to trigger and then inspect the state of the data inside using debugger.